# App crashes when retrieving data from Firebase database into ListView

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to retrieve data from a Firebase database into a ListView but the app get crashes a few seconds after opening a blank activity. When I open the activity on which I want to retrieve the data it remains blank for 3 to 4 seconds, then crashes.

Main java:

```
public class home extends AppCompatActivity {


    DatabaseReference mref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    ListView mlistview;
    ArrayList < String > arrayList = new ArrayList < > ();
    ArrayAdapter < String > arrayAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

        mlistview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);

        DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
            .getReferenceFromUrl("https://stark-1dffd.firebaseio.com/users");
        //mref=new Firebase("https://stark-1dffd.firebaseio.com/users");
        arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter < String > (this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, arrayList);
        mlistview.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
        mref.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                String value = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);

                arrayList.add(value);
                arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });

    }
}
```

Logcat:

```
Process: com.food.sheenishere.stark, PID: 12421

com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Failed to convert value of 
type java.util.HashMap to String

at com.google.android.gms.internal.zg.zzb(Unknown Source)

at com.google.android.gms.internal.zg.zza(Unknown Source)

at com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot.getValue(Unknown Source)

at com.food.sheenishere.stark.home$1.onChildAdded(home.java:49)

at com.google.android.gms.internal.px.zza(Unknown Source)

at com.google.android.gms.internal.vj.zzHX(Unknown Source)

at com.google.android.gms.internal.vp.run(Unknown Source)

at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)

at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)

at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)

at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)

at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)

at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller
.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)

at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

Comment: i have edited my question with logcat

Comment: Thank you. Now, what do you think the error is trying to tell you? Hint: `getValue(String.class)` is wrong. Your snapshot is not a string

Comment: `DataSnapshot` is probably Map so try it as `Map<String, String> valueMap = (HashMap<String, String>) dataSnapshot.getValue();`

Comment: Your data is either some object or directly a Map, anyway, is not a String. Please provide with a JSON sample of your data as recommended in the next comment.

Comment: @cutiko Please prefer asking for the actual JSON over a screenshot. Having the JSON as text makes it searchable, allows us to easily use it to test with your actual data and use it in our answer and in general is just a Good Thing to do. You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data)..

Comment: i have edited my question with screen shot of my database

Comment: why u using `getReferenceFromUrl?.` you can use `.getReference("users")`.

Comment: @jerinamathews thanks a lot finally it works...

Comment: happy to help..